# How to spawn an object on collision in box2d + love2d?

Tags: box2d, love2d

I'm trying spawn collidable debris from a ship when it explodes in love2d/box2d, however,  World:isLocked() is true when collision callbacks are called:

> This will return true inside the callbacks from World:setCallbacks.
>   ([source](http://love2d.org/wiki/World%3aisLocked))

So creating a new body throws an error. Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to solve this is to create the objects once the physics-simulation has completed.

In your collision callback you would push all the objects you want to create into a list-like data-structure. Once your physics-simulation-step is complete (eg. *after* `world:update`), create the objects/bodies that have been pushed to the list (thereby removing them from the list, so that they don't get created multiple times).

Comment: OK, I guess that is the simplest way to do it then. Thanks :D